How many distinct phonon branches will I see for 3 atoms in the unit cell, along the [100] direction?
Silicon (Si) crystallises in the fcc cubic structure with two atoms in the primitive unit cell.

How many acoustic and optical phonon branches does it have?
How many distinct branches in the dispersion curves do you expect for the phonons with the momentum along the [100] direction in the reciprocal space to be observed in a neutron diffraction experiment?

I am having trouble with this question. In 3D I will have 6 degrees of freedom and hence 6 phonon bands. I will have 3 optical bands and 3 acoustic bands. But how many distinct bands will I see that is parallel to [100]? I am thinking that since we have 2 acoustic bands that are transverse and 1 longitudinal then along the [100] direction, the 2 TA bands will be degenerate and the LA band will not. The optical bands will all be distinct. Hence I should see 5 distinct bands along [100]?
Am I right or wrong? If I am wrong then please explain why so, because I am not sure about this answer.

Googling "silicon phonon dispersion curve" readily brings up plots.

Okay I have done that and I see that the graphs show 3 distinct lines. But I do not understand why is it 3?
